# Pasar de un viewcontroller1 a un segundo viewcontroller2 con código en xcode swift3

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy intentando pasar de un `viewcontroller1` a un `viewcontroller2` pero solamente con código (sin navigation controller).

He intentado varios ejemplos sin éxito, puede que ya estén un poco desactualizados.

Comment: No pones nada de lo que has intentado. No sabemos si tienes un UINavigationController o no. Prueba con esto: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60232/pasar-de-un-viewcontroller1-a-un-segundo-viewcontroller2-con-codigo-en-xcode-swi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let vc = ViewController2() //Aquí iría tu view Controller2
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Con Swift 3

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciono a la perfeccion

Comment: también funciona así.. self.present(uViewController, animate: true )
el completion lo puedes eliminar; viene de swift 3.